# How to improve my huge code for new column with iterable maximum with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get a column that will contain an updatable maximum with each new value
I wrote the code, but it is very inconvenient, maybe there is a way easier in Pandas?

```
data =pd.DataFrame({
'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'Belarus', 'Russia','Brazil'],
'population': [1, 25, 2, 100, 100000]})
for i in data['population']:
    # check index array now
    index_now = data.index[data.population == i]
    print(data.loc[:index_now[0]]['population'].max())
```

I expect +new column 'iterable maximum' with [1, 25, 25, 100, 100000]
This maximum of this + all previous columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [cumulative max](http://docs.w3cub.com/pandas~0.22/generated/pandas.series.cummax/), and it's build in already.

```
data['iterable maximum'] = data.population.cummax()
```